# 403 Response code - Request Blocked when using Cowin setu APIs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-cloudfront, rest

I was just trying to make covid vaccine alert using Cowin Setu API (India) in nodejs. But I am facing some strange thing, whenever I hit get request I got 403 response code from cloudfront says 'Request Blocked' but the same is working from postman as well as from browser. Please help me in this

Getting this error:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Request blocked.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: Q1RZ94qgFp6AjUUKE4e9urMB85VejcqMbaJO6Y8Xq5Qp4kNjDBre9A==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Here's my nodejs code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const axios = require("axios");
const { Telegram } = require("telegraf");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
var cors = require('cors');
var request=require('request');


const tg = new Telegram(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
const bot = new Telegram(process.env.BOT_TOKEN, {
polling: true
});

//bot.start((ctx) => ctx.reply('Welcom to Covid Vaccine Finder'))

/*bot.hears("about", ctx => {
ctx.reply("Hey, I am CoviBot!");
});
bot.launch();*/

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());



app.use(
bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: true
})
);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
res.send("Welcom to Covid Vaccine Finder");
});

app.get("/test", function(req, res, next) {
var d = new Date();
var options = {
year: "numeric",
month: "2-digit",
day: "2-digit"
};

var date = String(d.toLocaleDateString("en", options));
date = date.replace(/\//g, "-");
console.log(date);

const URL =
"https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByPinpincode=110088&date=13-05-2021";

var options = { 
url: URL,
method: 'GET',
headers: {
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,hu;q=0.4',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    Connection: 'keep-alive',
    Host: 'cdn-api.co-vin.in',
    'User-Agent': 'request',


 }
 };
 request(options,function(err,res,body){
  let json = body;
 console.log(json);
 });


const txt = "Finding vaccine centres for you....";
//tg.sendMessage(process.env.GROUP_ID, txt);
res.send(txt);


});



 // Finally, start our server
 app.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
 console.log("Covid app listening on port 3000!");
 });
```

**I hope this problem will solve**

**Thanks**

Comment: No it's not, because it is working from postman or through curl

Comment: Yes, problem is coming only when I hit request from code

Comment: Yes, what should I write in host then?

Comment: I am using 3rd party AP, and I think it is hosted on cloudfront

Comment: Let's start again... where does your express app run? Are you running it locally or deploying it somewhere?

Comment: deployed it on glitch: https://covid-vaccine-finder.glitch.me

Comment: Does it work when you run it locally (like with `npm start`)?

Comment: No, same problem is coming

Comment: In that case, try changing the `User-Agent` request header. If `curl` works, try `"User-Agent": "curl/7.75.0"`

Comment: this is not working, but I have added 'req' as user agent and now it is working locally, still facing this problem after deploy

Comment: @shivamsharma, am facing similar issue. Works fine on local devevelopment, but when I tried to deploy to production environment, the API returns a 403. My suspicion is that in production environments, the reverse proxy server (Apache/NginX) might be adding/manipulating some Http headers which the Co-Win API doesn't support. Planning to try deploying somewhere as a raw Node server Https server. Will update here if that works.

Comment: Yes, please update

Comment: @shivamsharma Any updates on this one , I'm also facing the same issue,the axios.get() works completely fine on Local server but when deployed,it returns the status code 403 on Heroku log

Comment: Did not find anything till now

Answer (score 7):

I added a `user-agent` header to the request so that the API would recognize that my request is coming from a browser, rather than a script.

```py
headers = {
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
}
url = "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/calendarByDistrict?district_id=303&date="+date
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Since you are explaining the same question and your description does not contain a solution for the problem, I believe it is better put as a comment to the question rather than an answer.

Comment: Still Not Working

Comment: try it worked for me --- headers = {"Accept-Language": "hi_IN", "user-agent": "insomnia/2021.2.2"}

Comment: It is not working for me, can you please help

Answer (score 3):

Use following

```
var options = { 
url: URL,
method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        Host: 'cdn-api.co-vin.in',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'
    }
};
```

Comment: I guess it's related, but even if I force headers, somehow the API calls still fails when I tried from prod enviroments like Firebase Cloud Functions and Vercel. The headers might be manipulated by reverse proxy servers I guess. Still debugging this!

Answer (score 3):

Try These Headers They worked for me on local server (not production)

```
    let options = {
    headers: {
      "user-agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36",
    },
  };
```

These will not work in production because Cowin APIs are geofenced and can't be accessed from  IP address other than Indian. In most free hosting sites like Heroku, Indian IP is not an option. So alternative solution might be to use AWS, GCP, Azure with an Indian server (not tried yet).

Reference - https://github.com/cowinapi/developer.cowin/issues/228

Comment: The issue was something which no one would have expected. Very nice debugging!!! It was indeed geofenced, and cloudfront firewall wont allow request from outside INDIA

Answer (score 1):

It seems the api is blocked from using outside India. Try to combine some Indian proxy/use in Indian server

Answer (score 0):

You have to use User Agent Identifier API
Please refer this
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/useragentidentifier#using-with-python

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your request in the following format, I am attaching sample format for states metadata API:

curl --location --request GET 'https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states' --header 'Accept-Language: hi_IN' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header **'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'**

Answer (score 0):

Its not about the request user-agent or format. I faced the same issue and further testing proved cloudFront is blocking the IP if multiple requests are coming from same IP back to back. Its also unblocking after couple minutes.
Basically they don't want these alerting this, probably its overloading their server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you want to work local you can use

```
 let headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json', 
    'Accept-Language': 'hi_IN',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
}
```

Now if you want to deploy to Heroku or firebase, then it will return 403, I think it's mostly that they are blocking any IP hit outside from Indian server.

Github link: https://github.com/manojkumar3692/reactjs_nodejs_cowin

I Will keep you posted here